# Getting No Such File in Directory running wget script

Tags: 14.04, command-line, wget

I'm very new to Ubuntu and scripting. I am a Windows sysadmin. I need to schedule a .csv download once a day for my job.

First I tried to use the windows version of WGET and had was able to create this script but when using windows Task Scheduler it wouldn't work. I think maybe it had a problem with the script trying to run too fast and not allowing it to authenticate (just a guess).

```
F:\Exports\WGET\wget.exe -O F:\Exports\WGET\TEST\TEST_Export.csv "https://URLOMMITED" --no-check-certificate -r -P TEST
```

I couldn't figure it out so then I thought maybe I can install Ubuntu on a VM and give Ubuntu a shot since I know WGET is a linux command and have always wanted to use Ubuntu.

I opened gpedit and created this version of the script tested it on the Terminal by copy and paste and it works.

```
wget -O /home/gdadmin/Desktop/Exports/TEST.csv "https://URLOMMITED" --no-check-certificate
```

I saved it as test.sh on the Desktop and made it executable using:

```
chmod +x /home/gdadmin/Desktop/test.sh.
```

Then I tried opening the terminal to run the script:

```
./home/gdadmin/Desktop/test.sh
```

I get:

```
bash: ./home/gdadmin/Desktop/qual.sh: No such file or directory
```

I'm reading that I may be missing dependencies but I'm not sure what to do. I am just trying turn it into a executable file so that I can then figure out how to schedule it. I am planning on reading about using Crontab but first I want to test it as a file so I can start trying to run it on Crontab.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: so you typed test.sh and it responded no such file or directory qual.sh?

Comment: You are trying to refer to an **absolute  path** `/home/gdadmin/Desktop/qual.sh` but are prepending `.` so that the system is looking for `/home/gdadmin/Desktop/qual.sh` **relative** to your current directory.

Comment: @steeldriver do post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Stop!  Hold your horses!**

You've installed a VM tu run one *single* command?  Windows *is* a fully compliant POSIX OS (meaning: it's "kind of compatible" with Unix) and you don't need a VM for that!

Your problem is the `https://` and using `--no-certificate` is not going to cut it if that server needs log-in information!  So the `URL OMITTED` is actually needed to help you find a satisfying solution, as the [wget manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options.html) clearly states.

So you need to give more information **or** figure out yourself if the server needs certificates / keys / login information, ... to define the additional `wget` parameters you need to get the ssl/tls/... up and running so that `wget` can do its job...

(And you can make it fully work under Windows too, no Unix VM needed)

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)